# Controlling database record correctness

Tags: database, record, finance, correctness

What do you is the best possible strategy from a technical point of view of being sure that the data stored in the database is genuine and hasn't been changed, for example, by DBA ? Especially in cases when storing financial transaction data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up membership rule access to database/tables/DML operations and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't it still mean that there's at least one account (with privileges) that's able to edit data "silently"?

Comment: No, you create as much roles as you want and assign different access level for the each. And full access give only for yourself, for example. Or by request of somebody if you will allow it.

Comment: I get your idea, but a 3rd party looking at the DB records should be sure of data being genuine. It won't help me if I grant those privileges only to myself, because I could be a financial beneficiary of certain data. My question is - how do you make a 3rd party trust you? My idea was using some kind of hash chains maybe for sequential records or something similar. Or maybe there's more elegant way.

Comment: Do you mean inadvertent  changes? If so, then only way I see - add data integrity constraint on the database level, as you said. Hash is nice in this case. That is my opinion.